# Server "Kill" by itself

Tags: c

I'm doing a client-server app in C tryin' to emulate a card game.
It's a one-on-one game where the clients play the game assisted by a thread worker (one worker for each match). I was trying to do some tests but, at some point, with no reason at all, the server has crashed itself. The code is full of checks to try end it safely in every way. Post all the code is unthinkable but this is the result of the computation (I've repeated it more than 10 time obtaining the same result):

```
worker: Start Playing!
worker: hand number: 0
worker: player pluto playing on port 6!
Killed
```

any possible reason? someone else encountered the same problem?

Comment: ``Killed`` means that the process received SIGKILL, possibly from outside. You probably have to give more information to make people answer.

Comment: I've masked all the signal that the server could receive. SIGINT and SIGTERM are handled, SIGKILL is masked. I'm not doing anything that could possibly send a SIGKILL to my server!

Comment: @Janinho67 except that it does.

Comment: To clarify, SIGKILL is handled inside the kernel (scheduler probably) by just deallocating the process.

Comment: well.. so SIGKILL is uncontainable.. but from where this can come? Inside my code?? Somewhere else?

Comment: Besides some cronjob firing SIGKILL at random processes, literally everywhere.

Comment: I smell OOM killer. If you have an extreme memory leak, your program could be killed like this.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your program has been `kill -9`'d from some other program or script.

One common mysterious process killer is the Linux [out-of-memory (OOM) killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer). Under Linux when a program allocates too much memory you won't get a NULL back from `malloc()`, or an exception from the `new` operator. Instead your program will likely be `kill -9`'d by the kernel.

#### OOM Killer

Linux has a strange (but sensible) policy whereby it allows processes to allocate as much memory as they want, even if there's not enough memory to satisfy the requests. This is because many programs will optimistically allocate huge gobs of memory but not actually *use* all of that memory. Linux allows programs to allocate whatever they want, and only when they try to access that memory does Linux check that the memory exists.

If it doesn't, the kernel's in a bind because it has told the program that memory was available (i.e. `malloc()` returned a valid pointer earlier) and now it's been caught in a lie. There's no good way to signal an error to the program that oops, I made a mistake, I should have returned NULL earlier.

This is where the OOM killer kicks in. The OOM killer is like an airline that's overbooked a flight and now has to convince paying customers not to take that flight. I know you paid, but maybe somebody would be so kind as to take a later flight?

The kernel can't satisfy the memory request, so what can it do? It can say "sorry, I lied" and kill the current program. Or it can kill other programs to free up memory until there's enough free for the current program. The OOM killer tries to make the best of a bad situation. It tries to figure out what the best programs to kill are so as to minimize the damage. If there's some newly-started program that's chewing up huge gobs of memory, that's who it will kill. Which makes sense. There's a good chance that program has a bug in it causing it to allocate way too much memory.

Or consider another possibility: your program is totally innocent, but some *other* program is misbehaving and the OOM killer has decided to kill *yours*.

I have no idea if this is what's happening. But when I hear "my program is being killed for no reason" I think [OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer), because I've been burned by this bastard before.

Comment: Wanting to add that at least for some versions, the linux kernel had the opinion that the program allocating lots of memory is _not_ the one to kill, as it might be doing relevant stuff. They possibly tweaked that policy a bit in the meantime though.

Answer (score 0):

"Killed" is the message printed when your program received `SIGKILL`. `SIGKILL` is not catchable or maskable, meaning that it is guaranteed to kill your program (`SIGKILL` usually is signal 9, leading to the common idiom `kill -9 <pid>` to kill a process).

If you're not triggering `kill -9` somewhere, then the likely culprit is the OOM killer. @JohnKugelman gives a good overview of the killer.

You can determine if the OOM killer killed your process by looking in `/var/log/messages`:

```
grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
```